# How to group a struct by a specific pattern in C

Tags: c, struct, grouping

Following up from my previous question, I'm looking for a way to organize the following structure by category *as it is right now*, but sorting it between groups.

E.g., Group `Meats` is larger than group `Drinks`, so the `Meats` group should be above `Drinks`, and so on.

So far I understand the part using `qsort()`, but not sure about the grouping part. Here's the output I'm looking for (I'm definitely open for better ways of doing this)

```
                 Meats   -   43.00
         Meats,Chicken   -   27.00
            Meats,Beef   -   9.00
            Meats,Pork   -   4.00
          Meats,Turkey   -   3.00

                Drinks   -   33.00
         Drinks,Coffee   -   20.00
          Drinks,Pepsi   -   10.00
            Drinks,Tea   -   3.00

                Fruits   -   25.00
         Fruits,Grapes   -   13.00
          Fruits,Melon   -   10.00
          Fruits,Apple   -   2.00
```

*Working code:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct st_ex {
    char product[96];
    float price;
};

int struct_cmp_by_product(const void *a, const void *b) {
    struct st_ex *ia = (struct st_ex *)a;
    struct st_ex *ib = (struct st_ex *)b;

    int p;
    char *iaa = ia->product, *ibb = ib->product;
    while (1) {
        int c = *iaa;
        int d = *ibb;
        if(c == ',') c = 0;
        if(d == ',') d = 0;
        if(c != d || !c || !d) {
            p = c - d; break;
        }
        ++iaa;
        ++ibb;
    }
    if (p) return p;
    return ia->price < ib->price;
}

int main() {
    struct st_ex structs[] = {
        {"Fruits", 25},
        {"Meats,Beef", 9},
        {"Fruits,Apple", 2},
        {"Meats,Chicken", 27},
        {"Fruits,Grapes", 13},
        {"Meats", 43},
        {"Fruits,Melon", 10},
        {"Meats,Pork", 4},
        {"Meats,Turkey", 3},
        {"Drinks,Tea", 3},
        {"Drinks,Coffee", 20},
        {"Drinks,Pepsi", 10},
        {"Drinks", 33},

    };
    size_t structs_len = sizeof(structs) / sizeof(struct st_ex);
    qsort(structs, structs_len, sizeof(struct st_ex), struct_cmp_by_product);
    size_t i;
    for(i=0; i<structs_len; i++)
        printf("%30s   -   %.2f\n", structs[i].product, structs[i].price);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `struct_cmp_by_product()` appears to modify the underlying structs. Did I read that correctly? Are you confident you want to do this? Most people would consider sorting an operation that effects only the "container" and not the objects...

Comment: I'm definitely open for better ways of doing this, but so far that's what I thought. The struct contains a lot of products, so I need to consider the performance. Ideas are always appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a more involved data type so that you can group by price and category. Also, the simplest approach will need two sorts (so, you've two sort functions). Something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct category {
    char name[ 12 ];
    float price;
};

struct group {
    char name[ 12 ];
    float price;
    struct category cats[ 5 ]; // use a linked-list; this is for demo  
};

int cmp_by_group(const void *a, const void *b) {
    struct group const *ia = a;
    struct group const *ib = b;

    return (ia->price < ib->price);
}

int cmp_by_category(const void *a, const void *b) {
    struct category const *ia = a;
    struct category const *ib = b;

    return (ia->price < ib->price);
}

int main() {    
    struct group structs[] = {
        {"Fruits", 25, {{"Apple", 2}, {"Grapes", 13}, {"Melon", 10}}},
        {"Meats", 43, {{"Beef", 9}, {"Chicken", 27}, {"Pork", 4}, {"Turkey", 3}}},
        {"Drinks", 33, {{"Tea", 3}, {"Coffee", 20}, {"Pepsi", 10}}}
    };
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        qsort(structs[ i ].cats, 3, sizeof(struct category), cmp_by_category);
    }

    size_t structs_len = sizeof(structs) / sizeof(struct group);
    qsort(structs, structs_len, sizeof(struct group), cmp_by_group);
    size_t i;
    for(i=0; i<structs_len; i++) {
        printf("%s   -   %.2f\n", structs[i].name, structs[i].price);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            printf("%s,%s   -   %.2f\n", structs[i].name, structs[i].cats[ j ].name, structs[i].cats[ j ].price);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(You will need to fix the justification part though.)

Comment: I like the idea of separating it into two `structs` as opposed to dealing only with one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would print the aggregate value for a group after the individual values, rather than before them, as it is a whole lot easier to program.  So, the summary line for 'Meats' would appear after the 4 detail lines for 'Meats,Xxxx'.

Since you want to print the data in decreasing order of category, you are going to have to make two passes over the data, I believe.  In pass 1, you'll accumulate the aggregate (SUM) of the different categories (Meats, Drinks, Fruits).  In pass 2, you'll sort the data on two criteria — the aggregate for the category, and then by price within the category.  I would expect to do some pre-processing on the data to make it easier to sort, splitting the category out.  You'll also need to decide how to keep the SUM for category.  I think that the structure you sort should likely have extra fields for category and for the sum of prices within category.  You can then sort the data fairly easily on the second pass.

So, I think the outline processing might be:

```
struct reporting
{
    char     category[32];
    float    cat_sum;
    char     product[96];
    float    price;
};
```

- Scan the `struct st_ex` data records creating a `struct reporting` record for each `struct st_ex` record and creating an additional `struct reporting` record for each category:

  - Identify category and make sure there is a `struct reporting` record for the category (with the `category` and `product` fields containing the same string).
  - Add the `st_ex` price to relevant category (aggregate).
  - Copy the `struct st_ex` record into its own `struct reporting` record.
- Add the category records (type `struct reporting`) to the list to be sorted.

  - The `price` and `cat_sum` values in each of the category records will be the same.
  - The `category` and `product` values in each of the category records will be the same.
- Set the `cat_sum` for each `struct reporting` record to the `price` value in the category records (so each Meats record has the same value for the `cat_sum`).
- Sort the `struct reporting` records by:

  - Descending order of `cat_sum`.
  - Descending order of `category` (just in case two categories happen to share the same `cat_sum`).
  - Descending order of `price`.
  - Descending order of `product` (just in case two products share the same category and price).
- Print the records in the sorted order.

This becomes a control-break report at this point.  A Google search on 'control-break report' finds some useful material, but (just for once) the Wikipedia page is not one of the places to get information from (it is an orphaned page and just a stub).

---

I hope that's clear enough, but it isn't my best ever explanation, I fear.  I think the ideas are sound, but I can understand what I'm trying to say — I'm not sure whether this helps others or not.